# How to move slick slider and my div in same line

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, slider, carousel

I am trying to implement an HTML slider with heading information in first.

I created below jsfiddle but I am not able to bring Heading column and slider in the same line. (No line Break)

I tried using `col-md` but it did not help.

```
<div class="col-md-1 text-right my-2">
    <table />
</div>
<div class="col-md-11 my-2">
    <slider />
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rushijoshi/hb2aot65/7/

Expected Output, see the Image : 
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSITg.png)

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Rushi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `row` class to their parent `<div>`??

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 text-right my-3">
        <table />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 m-3">
        <slider />
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/ht4beqcx/3/

If you like to keep the fixed left column and the slider in one line, you will need to add `flex-nowrap` to the row to make the row not wrappable:

```
<div class="row flex-nowrap">
    <div class="col-2 text-right my-3">
        <table />
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 my-3 mx-auto">
        <slider />
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/ht4beqcx/12/

Comment: Thanks David, this was so simple but I did not think of. I marked as answer. I need one more favor, my original idea was to make it responsive and on Mobile device that slider reduces to 2 columns only.  It is working like that in your JSFiddle but that first fixed column is taking whole space and not giving responsiveness. If you can help me then it would be great.

Comment: I updated your fiddle and play with col-xs but no luck, In mobile devices it is still going to the next line. Anything can be help. https://jsfiddle.net/rushijoshi/hnjteL9p/

Comment: @RushikeshJoshi: sorry I don't get what you want. So you want to keep the first fixed column and the reduced slider in the same row for mobile devices?

Comment: Yes David, you were right. Your provided solution is not keeping slider and that fixed thing in one line. Though my slider reduces to 2 slides for mobile, still they are showing up in two lines. You can see by opening in mobile device : https://jsfiddle.net/rushijoshi/hnjteL9p/embedded/result/

Comment: @RushikeshJoshi: I've updated the post. See if that works out for you.